# I need help understanding the syntax for BACKUP in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

So, I am relatively new to MySQL and recently, I was asked to create a query that utilizes the BACKUP command in order to copy a table to a given destination folder. I was provided text from an SQL tutorial in w3schools.com, however, when I attempted to follow the format, I was informed that "BACKUP is not valid at this position, expecting: EOF, BEGIN, CATCH, CHECKSUM, COMMIT, DEALLOCATE,..". So, I was wondering, what is the proper syntax for using the BACKUP command in a query?

I have attempted several actions in order to resolve the issue, but none of them were successful. I have tried;

1# Executing a query with and without the underlying table saved in a file folder.

2# Using BACKUP for a database in case the problem was with tables.

3# Starting with BEGIN, DO, and mysqldump.

4# Removing TABLE.

5# Adding an opening parenthesis after the name of the table and a closing parenthesis after the name of the destination.

I do not feel comfortable sharing my own table and destination folder, but here is what I was supposed to use for reference. My code follows the same format;

[What I was supposed to use for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yc9B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BACKUP DATABASE` Is not part of MySQL syntax.  I believe you may be thinking of the [SQL Server statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

For MySQL you will likely want to use the [mysqldump utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) (which is a separate concept from SQL queries).  Or possibly some solution involving the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` variant of [the SELECT...INTO statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html).